# Not able to pass data using Dataprovide

Tags: arrays, object, dataprovider

I have a requirement to create multiple user using web driver. Hence, I chose data provider to fulfill the requirement. Below is the script which I am trying but am unable to pass the data.

public class MultipleUserCreation {

```
@Test(dataProvider="senddata")
public void UserCreation(String userId,String firstName,String lastName,String displayName,String email) throws IOException {
```

XXX -- have used login script here

then  am using the below

```
enter code here
  @DataProvider(name="senddata")
  public java.lang.Object[][] passData()
  { 
    Object[][] data=new Object[1][5];
    data[0][0]="RS004AUTOM";
    data[0][1]="KUMAR";
    data[0][2]="NARAYANAN";
    data[0][3]="KUMARAT";
    data[0][4]="kumar.narayanan@yahoo.com";
```

}
}
when the script runs, it does not pass the data and those fields are still blank even after script successfully completed.

Please help..